# command line on esxi cant get date X day ago

Tags: date, busybox, esxi, esx

I'm currently working on an ESXI and want to get the date X day ago
I have this command line working on other linux :

```
now=`date +"%Y/%m/%d"`
earlier=`date -d "$now -15 days" +%d/%m/%Y`
```

but when i try to use it on my esxi server the line :

```
earlier=`date -d "$now -15 days" +%d/%m/%Y`
```

is not working, i get the error

```
date: invalid date '2018/01/30 -4 days'
```

So I tried to write the date in differents way like american format but still have the error.

the esxi version is 6.0.0

I have searched on internet but i didn't find anything.

Can someone know what is the problem ?
Thank you.

edit: for those having the same problem i got the solution in the comments below

Comment: @tripleee looks interesting but it's for the last saturday, i'll try to figure out how to do it. thank you

Comment: The general approach will be the same, you have to use some external tool to calculate the time from the difference. Minus 15 days is -15 * 24 * 3600 seconds from now.

Comment: i got it but the output is wrong for me, I only need something as YYYY/MM/DD

Comment: That's easy to influence with something like `+"%Y/%m/%d"` though your current command actually has a different format string. For computer-readable output, `+%F` is probably what you should use (`+%Y-%m-%d` if Busybox doesn't have `%F`).

Comment: yes but the command you linked doesnt use +%F or +%Y-%m-%d it's using second to choose the day.

Comment: Exactly. You need to calculate the second, pass it in, and request the date format you want for the output with a `+%Y-%m-%d` or similar.

Comment: i can add +%Y-%m-%d but i cant rid of the second because if i do i cant substract X days. Or maybe i can store the result in a global variable and the annoying part

Comment: So roughly like `date -d "1970.01.01-00:00:$(date +'%s - 15 * 24 * 60 * 60' | xargs expr)" +%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: thank you so much, i tried to do this way but it didnt work because of wrong quote. Thank you again you really helped me

Comment: This is really just derived from the duplicate I nominated many comments ago. Please accept it.

Answer (score 5):

It turns out this is busybox date.  Busybox date is very limited in its abilities, but fortunately it supports (undocumentedly) the @seconds syntax:

```
date -d "@$(( $(busybox date +%s) - 86400 * 7 ))" +%d/%m/%Y
```

This of course requires that you have a modern version of bash.  If this command doesn't work, try typing "bash" and if that works try typing the command again.

If you don't have modern bash...then do you have awk or bc installed?  Python?  Perl?  Basically the tactical goal is to get date to spit out seconds, subtract 7 days worth of seconds, and then feed the output into date again to convert format.

### Old

Try this command line.  It avoids the $now reference which might confuse some versions of date.

```
date -d "15 days ago" +%d/%m/%Y
```

If this doesn't work, can you tell us which version of date you are using?  `date --version` and/or `date --help` should provide the necessary information.

Comment: it's not working, I got the error :

     date: invalid date '15 days ago'

Comment: which version of date i am looking for ? it says it recognize YYYY-MM-DD format

Comment: @user7394492 you need to tell us which version you have using the arguments I suggested. I suspect you cannot change the version of date easily.

Comment: ok thank, i think it's BusyBox v1.20.2

Comment: il found this : ./busybox date -D %s -d $(( $(./busybox date +%s) - 86400
where 86400 = 1 days in second but it's not working